# How to view all items of Errors under Problems View in Eclipse Editor

Tags: java, eclipse

I had checked out a Project from Our CVS. When I tried to build it in Eclipse by adding some jars, it showed a lot of errors under the Problems View in Eclipse.

It displayed nearly 12,000 errors, but I could see only the first 100 of those 12,000 errors.
Could anybody please explain how I can see the next 100 errors?

And I don't know why, but after I check out from CVS I am also getting these errors.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

On Eclipse Helios click on the triangle pointing down on the `Problems` view, select `Preferences` then in the Preference dialog that appear, you can change the `Limit visible items per group` to change the value. Or else uncheck `Use marker limits` checkbox to allow all items being visible.

[image]

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate for recent Eclipse versions - see answers below

Comment: Well I did mention that the answer is for `Eclipse Helio` in the very beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 28):

there is a triangle pointing down on the problems view, click on it, click configure contents, there will be "Number of items visible per groups:", change it

[image: http://sadpanda.us/images/875726-7ODRIBW.png]

Comment: Hi , Please see the screen shot , i could not find anything when i click on that triangle , please see the screen shot pasted in my actual question

Answer (score 20):

Just click on the arrow down in the Perspective and select Group by None.[image]

or

Configure Contents...

[image]
[image]

Comment: But still its displaying first 100 only .

Comment: In 2019-06, it's called `Filters...` but same window with "Use limits" checkbox at bottom.

Answer (score 11):

In Eclipse Oxygen : Click the down triangle on the Markers panel, select Filters... , then untick the Use Limits check box in the pop up and then click OK.

Comment: Confirmed also for Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0), Build ID 20180917-1800.

Answer (score 4):

[image: How to view all items of Errors under Problems View in Eclipse Editor]

Change the Fitter setting as following

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are all valid, but in Java, there is a further limit configured in the compiler preferences. This is why you may continue to see 100 items.

[This article](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2009/08/26/how-to-get-eclipse-to-show-more-than-100-errorswarnings/) describes where to find the preference in question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's changed again - none of these answers seem to be valid with the current 2021-x versions.

First, find the Problems tab and look to the very right where you will find the **Filters...** button:

[image]

Once inside the Filters panel, look down in the bottom-left corner and either uncheck the **Use limits** checkbox or increase the limit from 100:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had once a less obvious, maybe rare case where no errors and warnings were shown in the problems view. I was wondering why I don't see any entries, although I see a certain number of errors and warnings in the header of the problems view. All filters were switched off. It looked like that:

[image: Number of errors and warnings shown, but no entries]

I found out that in my case the "Description" column was so small that I didn't realize, there is another column with entries that are just not visible. Resizing the column made the grouped warnings and entries visible again.

[image: Entries visible again]