# Eclipse IDE, warning view displays only first 100 items

Tags: eclipse, ide

I am using eclipse IDE for java development. The issue at hand is problems view displays only first 100 error items or warning items. Is there any possibility to increase the number of error or warning items in the problems view.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719605/eclipse-how-to-view-all-items-of-errors-under-problems-view-in-eclipse-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the far right you'll see the Error Log's toolbar and a drop down triangle. If you open the menu by hitting the triangle you'll see a "Filters..." entry. If you open the dialog there's a place to set how many elements to show.